# no hand joints over holographic remoting

Tags: unity-game-engine, remoting, hololens

I use Holographic Remoting Player to project the unity uwp program to HoloLens. I can get the unity picture on HoloLens, move around to move the field of view, have the hand laser and air tap working well, but the hand joint visualization doesn't show up.

The player setting is ok. And I have followed the troubleshooting steps in this link, everything is ok, but the hand joint still doesn't work.
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Tools/HolographicRemoting.html#msbuildforunity-package-import-via-writing-into-the-packagemanifest

I have tried in Unity 2019.2.4 and 2019.4.1, both the same result. Is there anything misconfigured I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/4292feb0321178bca5b7e3dd2af0232828212b22/Documentation/Updating.md#profile-changes-in-210), the hand tracking profile has been updated to allow for setting the hand joint visualization to: Nothing, Everything, Editor or Player. It meaning it is possible to turn on/off hand joint visualizations while in the editor or in the device or both. So it might be a good idea to double check this field in your MRTK profile and the following way is worth trying:

Click the `MixedRealityToolkit` object in the Hierarchy window, and then navigate to `Input`->`Hand Tracking` in Inspector window, find `HandJointVisualizationModes` field and set to `Everything`.